# How to decrypt a randomly generated encrypted value in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, encryption

I am trying to decrypt an encrypted string value.Every time string value is encrypted in to a random value.But I couldn't get the original value when decrypted.It 's a blank doesn't print any thing.This my code.

```
get( keys, value) {
    const key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(keys);
   
    const iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(128 / 8);
    const encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(value.toString()), key,
      {
        keySize: 128 / 8,
        iv,
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
      });

    return encrypted.toString();

    }

    set(keys, value) {
      const key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(keys);
      const iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(128 / 8);
      const decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(value, key, {
        keySize: 128 / 8,
        iv,
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
      });
      return decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
    }

   this.encryptedId = this.Service.get('1$#@^@1EFR#', this.code);
   this.decryptedId = this.Service.set('1$#@^@1EFR#', params.id);
```

If i use `const iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(keys);` instead of `const iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(128 / 8);` it 's working. But every time encrypt to a same value.How to decrypt a randomly encrypted value?

Comment: For decryption you have to use the **same** IV that you used for encryption.

Comment: But if i use different one also it's  not working

Comment: It's not suppose to work if you use a different one. You must use the **same** one.

Comment: I want to generate a random encrypted value every time.Not the same encrypted value.If i use same  `const iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(keys);` it 's not generating a random value

Comment: No, I'm not talking about that. The problem is that you are generating a random IV in the **decryption** code. You can't do that, you have to use the same IV you generated for **encryption**. Not the same method, but the same exact IV.